# Additionl vertical axis in Google Charts (Column)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I tried to create [Column Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) ([Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/)) with automatically generated vertical axis and one special, additional, featured, vertical axis set by me (custom vertical axis).

I painted this picture to show what I mean:
[image]

..and this is my code without custom axis:

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
   var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Col.name');
   dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Stage 1');
   dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Stage 2');
   dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Stage 3');
   dataTable.addRows([
      ['Current quarter', 0, 0, 1300],
      ['Annual summary', 300, 600, 1300]
   ]);
   var options = {
      isStacked: true,
   };
   new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/QjQNX/1004/

---

I cannot find any solution in [Google Charts Documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart). 
I found only **vAxis.ticks** option, but it replaces the automatically generated axis!